# map view custom annotation view images not loading properly in device

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview

i am using multiple annotation views with different images in my map view.  Images are loading properly in simulator but not in device.i am not able to figure out the reason for this issue..following is my code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString * const annotationIdentifier = @"CustomAnnotation";

    annotationView1 = [mapUrCommView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView2 = nil;
    if (annotationView1)
    {
        annotationView1.annotation = annotation;
        if(mapUrCommView.userInteractionEnabled)
            annotationView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MapPinDarkBlue75@2x.png"];//   map-pin-black.png
        else
        {
            //if(annotationView1.annotation == self.currentAnnotation|| annotation == self.previousAnnotation)
            NSLog(@"in annotation view 1");
            annotationView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapDrawPoint@2x.png"];//  Bluedot.png
        }

        annotationView1.tag=111;
        return annotationView1;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView2 = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
        annotationView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MapPinDarkBlue75@2x.png"];// map-pin-black.png

        annotationView2.canShowCallout = YES;
        return annotationView2;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

here i am drawing physical boundaries for a location in my app...so annotation view 1 is view which i am drawing presently & annoation view 2 will be having all annotations custom view images(all annotations will be having same images) which i already drawn in past..custom annotaion images are loading fine in simulator but not in device

Answer (score 0):

It's worked me for using custom class for annotation.. Please refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/MapCallouts.zip) sample [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html).

1.) Allocate MapAnnotation

```
    mapAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];
```

2.) Set Coordinate for your lat and long

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[NBCGPSLocation sharedInstance].gpsLatitude doubleValue], [[NBCGPSLocation sharedInstance].gpsLongitude doubleValue]);
    [mapAnnotation setCoordinate:coord];
    [self.mapSDKView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
```

3.) Now this delegate method will call once you go that lat and long location

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
     {
         if(!customAnnotationView)
             customAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]init];
         customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locationCustom"];

         customAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

         return customAnnotationView;
     }
    else
    {
        if(!annotationView)
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]init];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locationIcon"];
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        return  annotationView;
    }
}
```

Comment: using this method  custom view annotation images are not even loading in simulator...

Comment: @ravindersingh Add the image in Asset folder then use that name in code.

Comment: how would it help in loading images?

Comment: can u please post the code of custom Annotation class ? @Yano Ratheez

Comment: Please check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/MapCallouts.zip